# How to properly copy entire s3 bucket with exactly same permissions

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, kops

I'm trying to make a copy of **s3 bucket on aws** and it is really pain.

- My **reference** s3 bucket is: **s3://original**
- Duplicated ver. of this bucket: **s3://original-copy**

**My goal is:**

- generate **kubernetes.tf** file with `kops create cluster ...` => **DONE**
- **kops** is kind enough to create `--state=s3://original` => **DONE**
- now I want to create a new `s3 bucket` with **exactly** same content as in `s3://original` just the name is different `s3://original-copy` => **PROBLEM**

**Command**

```
aws s3 cp s3://original  s3://original-copy --recursive --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

Even though bucket is **duplicated** it seems like there is some problem with `s3 bucket` permissions

Then I am adjusting values in `terraform/data` folder with a new reference to `s3://original-copy` as well as at `s3://original-copy`

- `s3://original-copy/cluster_name/config`
- `s3://original-copy/cluster_name/cluster.spec`

files.

But there is a problem with permissions all the time.

**Error**:

> s3context.go:145] unable to get bucket location from region "us-east-1"; scanning all regions: AccessDenied: Access Denied

**Idea**

The main idea is that **kops** will generate

- `kubernetes.tf` file and `data` folder with proper files (all within `terraform folder`) just once
- `--state=s3://original` bucket just once

Once we have some example (patterns) of **s3** and **kuberetes.tf** we would stop using **kops**.

Comment: Why are you trying to copy the S3 bucket? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: look when you have `kubernetes.tf` defined just once by using kops then you need to run `terraform apply` which creates **EC2** on AWS. At the same time you have `--state=s3://...` properly defined which stores your **certificates and cluster specs**. By having this two things you do not need to run `kops create cluster ...` anymore. We just want to use **terraform ONLY**. In order to achive so we just need to know how to handle `s3 bucket` which seems to be a **big deal** so far

Comment: **We would like to avoid** using `kops` all over again when we need to start a new `kubernetes` cluster - that can be achieved if you have two things: 1) `kubernetes.tf` file and 2) proper `s3 bucket` sort of **prototypes** or reference